# Can not get delimitmate to work in vim

Tags: linux, vim, plugins, vim-plugin

I am trying to use delimitmate plugin but when I run vim I get:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>26_DelimitMateDo..<SNR>26_init..<SNR>26_option_init..<SNR>26_s:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: delimitMate#Set
E117: Unknown function: delimitMate#Set
Error detected while processing function <SNR>26_DelimitMateDo..<SNR>26_init..<SNR>26_g:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: delimitMate#Get
Error detected while processing function <SNR>26_DelimitMateDo..<SNR>26_init..<SNR>26_option_init..<SNR>26_s:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: delimitMate#Set
Error detected while processing function <SNR>26_DelimitMateDo..<SNR>26_init..<SNR>26_g:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: delimitMate#Get
Error detected while processing function <SNR>26_DelimitMateDo..<SNR>26_init:
line    8:
E712: Argument of filter() must be a List or Dictionary
delimitMate: each member of a pair in delimitMate_matchpairs must be different from each other.
line   11:
E712: Argument of map() must be a List or Dictionary
E714: List required
delimitMate: invalid pairs: 0
```

What am I messing up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have the `~/.vim/plugin/delimitMate.vim` script, but not the corresponding `~/.vim/autoload/delimitMate.vim` script. Depending on how you installed the plugin (unpack zip, VimBall, clone repository with Pathogen, install with Vundle etc.), you need to reinstall the *entire* plugin.

Though small and simple plugins just contain of a single script (to be placed in the `plugin/` config subdir), many plugins separate parts of the functionality into modules which are loaded on-demand, improving Vim's footprint and startup time. The module mechanism (introduce with Vim 7.0) is called *autoload*; cp. `:help autoload`. Those additional scripts must be placed in the proper `autoload/` config subdir for the plugin to work.

Comment: I just copied the delimitMate.vim under .vim/plugin/delimitMate.vim. Isn't this adequate?

Comment: I don't have an autoload directory (no pathogen)

Comment: Then create one, and copy / install the corresponding source file (not the plugin/delimitMate.vim!) there. From what did you install, anyway?

Comment: From here (https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) I downloaded the .zip file, unzipped it and coppied the delimitMate.vim to `.vim/plugin/delimitMate.vim`

Comment: Ah alright, then do the same with the script in the autoload subdir, creating `~/.vim/autoload` if necessary. (Optionally the same for the `doc` subdir, too.)

Comment: I created autoload and added delimitMate i.e. `.vim/autoload/delimitMate.vim` which I copied from `.vim/plugin/delimitMate.vim` but same problem

Comment: I redownloaded from (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2754) and recopied them and now I get differen error. When open vim no error. When I type e.g. `"` I get `E117: Unknown function: delimitMate#QuoteDelim                                                                                                            
E15: Invalid expression: delimitMate#QuoteDelim("\"")`

Comment: +1. I copied the `plugin/delimitMate.vim` in the autoload instead of the one under autoload in the zip file. Now it works. I will accept your answer.But could you please explain a bit in your answer why I need the autoload dir? I thought that this is needed for pathogen only.

Comment: Alright, glad you've managed to get it to work, though I don't fully follow. I'll add an explanation!